# How to get rid of If/else statements to call Razor Components

Tags: blazor

I have custom components, all they share the same [Parameters], so I receive a List and based on that list, I fill and dynamically call this pages and create a new page, so far so good, but i would like to implement a factory and interface but don't know how to achieve that in Blazor.

I want this to be decided inside a Factory

```
@foreach (var question in questions)
{
    QuestionNumber++;
    @if(question.Style == Style.Star)
    {
        <StarQuestion QuestionNumber="@QuestionNumber" QuestionID="@question.QuestionID" Title="@question.Title" Description="@question.Description" HasJustifyAnswer="question.HasJustifyAnswer" SurveyID="question.SurveyID"></StarQuestion>
    }
    @if(question.Style == Style.Heart)
    {
        <HeartQuestion QuestionNumber="@QuestionNumber" QuestionID="@question.QuestionID" Title="@question.Title" Description="@question.Description" HasJustifyAnswer="question.HasJustifyAnswer" SurveyID="question.SurveyID"></HeartQuestion>
    }
    @if(question.Style == Style.Bubble)
    {
        <BubbleQuestion QuestionNumber="@QuestionNumber" QuestionID="@question.QuestionID" Title="@question.Title" Description="@question.Description" HasJustifyAnswer="question.HasJustifyAnswer" SurveyID="question.SurveyID"></BubbleQuestion>
    }
    @if(question.Style == Style.Slider)
    {
        <SliderQuestion QuestionNumber="@QuestionNumber" QuestionID="@question.QuestionID" Title="@question.Title" Description="@question.Description" HasJustifyAnswer="question.HasJustifyAnswer" SurveyID="question.SurveyID"></SliderQuestion>
    }
    @if(question.Style == Style.Radio)
    {
        <RadioQuestion QuestionNumber="@QuestionNumber" QuestionID="@question.QuestionID" Title="@question.Title" Description="@question.Description" HasJustifyAnswer="question.HasJustifyAnswer" SurveyID="question.SurveyID"></RadioQuestion>
    }
    @if(question.Style == Style.ComboBox)
    {
        <ComboBoxQuestion QuestionNumber="@QuestionNumber" QuestionID="@question.QuestionID" Title="@question.Title" Description="@question.Description" HasJustifyAnswer="question.HasJustifyAnswer" SurveyID="question.SurveyID"></ComboBoxQuestion>
    }
}
```

I would like to do something similar to:

```
@foreach (var question in questions)
{
  component = Factory.GetQuestionComponent(question) //The component is created
  {
     <Render Dynamic component>
  }
}
```

It's all based on an Enum and the only change is the Component type, it should be easy on a regular c# app, each component would implement an interface, and a factory would implement the interface, so I use and extend when creating a new component, that way the main page would never change, and components always extend, but I'm struggling to achieve the same result on blazor.

Comment: Have you looked at [dynamically-rendered components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/dynamiccomponent?view=aspnetcore-6.0)?

Comment: Thanks, it solved my issue and the code is much more cleaner now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are VERY sure that all your question components will use the exact same pattern, `Style.XYZ goes to Pages.QuestionComponents.XYZQuestion`

Then you could reduce your resolution method down to a couple lines:

```
public Type? ResolveComponentType(Style style)
{
    var styleName = nameof(style);
    var typeName = $"Pages.QuestionComponents.{styleName}Question";
    return Type.GetType(typeName);
}
```

**Note:** The string you provide `GetType` must (I think) be the full namespace, right up to the project name.  I suspect it might be `YourProjectName.Pages.QuestionComponents.XYZQuestion`

**And note:** If you change the namespace of your questions, or you ever have a question component whose name doesn't match the Style.Name pattern exactly, then it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

The solution now

index.razor

```
@foreach (var question in questions)
{
    QuestionNumber++;
    Dictionary<string, object> component = new Factory().GetQuestionComponent(question, QuestionNumber);
    Type type = new Factory().ResolveComponentType(question.Style);
    <DynamicComponent Type="type" Parameters="component"></DynamicComponent>
}
```

Factory.cs

```
public class Factory
    {
        public Dictionary<string, object> Parameters { get; set; } = new();

        public Dictionary<string, object> GetQuestionComponent(QuestionModel question, int questionNumber)
        {
            return new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                ["QuestionID"] = question.QuestionID,
                ["QuestionNumber"] = questionNumber,
                ["Title"] = question.Title,
                ["Description"] = question.Description,
                ["HasJustifyAnswer"] = question.HasJustifyAnswer,
                ["SurveyID"] = question.SurveyID,
            };
        }

        public Type ResolveComponentType(Style style)
        {
            Type type = null;
            if (style == Style.Star)
                return typeof(Pages.QuestionComponents.StarQuestion);

            if (style == Style.Heart)
                return typeof(Pages.QuestionComponents.HeartQuestion);

            if (style == Style.Bubble)
                return typeof(Pages.QuestionComponents.BubbleQuestion);

            if (style == Style.Slider)
                return typeof(Pages.QuestionComponents.SliderQuestion);

            if (style == Style.Radio)
                return typeof(Pages.QuestionComponents.RadioQuestion);

            if (style == Style.ComboBox)
                return typeof(Pages.QuestionComponents.ComboBoxQuestion);

            return type;
        }
    }
```

Comment: When in doubt, usually go with Shaun's answers. :)

Answer (score 1):

Forget the `ifs`, you can do it more succinctly with a modern `switch` like this:

```
public Type? ResolveComponentType(Style style)
   => style switch
     {
         Style.Star => typeof(Pages.QuestionComponents.StarQuestion),
         Style.Heart => typeof(Pages.QuestionComponents.HeartQuestion),
         Style.Slider => typeof(Pages.QuestionComponents.SliderQuestion),
         //... more options followed by the default
         _ => null
     };
```